# Upgrading OS on GCP Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to upgrade the OS on GCP Compute Engine VM? Can I just run dist-upgrade or do I have to follow a different steps like taking a snapshot of the Disk and spin a new upgraded VM and mount the Disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a full inplace OS upgrade but it's not recommended. If for example there's a need to confirm anything during the reboot process you won't be able to do it remotely. You may try to use [serial console interaction](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) but it's always a risk.

It's best to [clone the VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-similar-instance) an try the upgrade on the copy first.

For the test purposes I've tested upgrading from `Debian 9 Stretch` to  `Debian 10 Buster`. Here's how:

First I've created a new GCP instance running Debian 9 (default settings); then I logged in via SSH and ran fallowing commands:

First I've changed `/etc/apt/sources.list` all `stretch` to `buster` occurences (necessary to go from 9 to 10) with `sudo sed -i 's/stretch/buster/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

and next ran:

- `lsb_release -a` - check current OS version

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:        9.13
Codename:       stretch
```

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade -y`
- `lsb_release -a` - verify after upgrade

If everything's OK you should see:

```
me@d9:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I was able to SSH into my instance using GCP console with no issues. As you can see I've used just "apt upgrade" since it will just upgrade installed packages. You can check the [difference between `upgrade` vs `dist-upgrade` in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/81594/1064087).

I can't say if it's possible with Red Hat or CentOS but I can make and educated guess and say it's possible in the same way as with Debian.

Comment: @John Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?